# в D (dmd) isNumeric не реагирует на число

Tags: d

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
void main() {
    string username;
    write("введите имя пользователя ");
    username = readln();
    if (!isNumeric(username)) {
        writeln("здравствуй, @", username);
    }
}
```

есть вот такой код на D.
Метод isNumeric не работает:

```
[me@me ~]$ dmd hello.d 
[me@me ~]$ ./hello
введите имя пользователя 45
здравствуй, @45
```

почему так работает и как исправить?

Comment: может быть потому что username - Это строка? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указано в описании метода [readln](https://dlang.org/library/std/stdio/readln.html)

> прочитанная строка включает ограничивающий символ.

По умолчанию - это перенос строки.

При передачи строки включающей кроме цифр перенос строки функция isNumeric возвращает false.

Поэтому перед передачей необходимо обрезать ненужные символы, например с помощью метода [`strip`](https://dlang.org/library/std/string/strip.html)

```
if (!isNumeric(strip(username))) {
```

Comment: спасибо, все понял. и почему именно так readln в d работает... странно.

Comment: @user232384, не могу сказать почему решили именно так.